# Order of a group and is it cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the multiplicative group of units modulo 20. What is the order of the group? Find the subgroups generated by 3 and 11. Is it cyclic?

Is my order 8 because the generators of 20 are {1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19)?

And the subgroup for 3 is {1,3,7,9} and for 11 it is {1,11}.

How do I know if it's cyclic?

Comment: What you list first are not the generators but the elements. -- The cyclic group of order $8$ has exactly one subgroup of order $4$ and exactly one subgroup of order $2$, which is a subgroup of the subgroup of order $4$

Answer (score 1):

Suposse that it is cyclic. Let $a$ be a generator. Since the order of $3$ is $4$ then $3=a^{2n}$ where $n$ is odd. Furthermore $11=a^4$. Then $3^2\cdot11=a^{4+4n}=1$, but $99\not\equiv 1\pmod{20}$. This contradiction shows that the group is not cyclic.

Comment: How is the order of 3, 4?

Comment: Well, the powers of 3 mod 20 are 3, 9, 7, 1